# Vectorizing a for loop which contains an iterator (Numpy Array)

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, vectorization

I am trying to make a python function run faster by taking advantage of the vectorization features in Numpy.

The aim of the function is that at the end of each iteration of the for loop, the location arr[i, 0] (i.e first entry of each row) will contain the number of rows in the 2D array (data), whose value if at position 0 is less than or equal to that or array i

```
# Data is a 2D array
def function(data)
    n = len(data)
    arr = np.zeros(shape=(n, 9))
    for i, sample in enumerate(data):
        arr[i][0] = np.count_nonzero(data[:, 0] <= data[i][0])
```

I am currently using a for loop. The runtime is horribly slow as this is being used in a machine learning algorithm. I have been told that I can further improve this by vectorizing the for loop.

I have tried this, in my attempt to use list comprehension:

```
arr[:, 0] = ( np.count_nonzero(data[:, x] >  data[i][x]) for i in gini_arr[:, 0] )
```

But I get a generator error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'
```

How can I vectorize this for loop?

Comment: `( np.count_nonzero(data[:, x] >  data[i][x]) for i in gini_arr[:, 0] )` this is not list comrehension it returns generator. add sample input and expected output

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Look at *arr = np.zeros(shape=(n*9)*. It contains unbalanced parentheses. Is it enough to add ")" at the end? And what are values of *n* and *data*?

Comment: I cannot paste the complete code here, this is just an extract which is supposed to convey what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment to my initial solution you wrote: *in column 0, no
element is less than 0*. So this brings me to a conclusion that in
your function there should be **<** instead of **<=**.

Another weird point is that you created a loop with one of control
variables named *sample* but you never use this variable.
A more natural solution is to iterate over a *range(n)* (you computed
*n* earlier, as the number of rows in *data*).

The last detail to correct in your code is that your function does
not return anything.

And one improvement: As you compute the **count** of elements meeting
some condition, the result is by definition an array of **integers**,
not *float*.

So the corrected content of your function (operating the old way)
should be:

```
def function(data):
    n = len(data)
    arr = np.zeros((n, 9), dtype=int)
    for i in range(n):
        arr[i, 0] = np.count_nonzero(data[:, 0] < data[i, 0])
    return arr
```

## How to compute this result in a vectorized way

You can get just the same result, when you define your function as:

```
def fn(data):
    dd = data[:, 0]  # The first column
    res = np.less(dd[np.newaxis, :], dd[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)
    return np.hstack([res[:, np.newaxis], np.zeros((dd.size, 8), dtype=int)])
```

Note that *res* (a *1-D* array) contains the result of comparison of
each element in *dd* with all elements in *dd*.

The final result is generated by:

- conversion of *res* to an array with a single column,
- "addition" of 8 columns filled with zeroes.

To test this function I created a test array:

```
data = np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1)
data[3,0] = 1
```

so that it contains:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 1, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Then I ran `fn(data)` getting:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For the above test data (5 rows) my function computed only 5 % faster
(107 µs yours and 101 µs mine).

But for a bigger number of rows, e.g. 60, your function completed
in 1.24 ms, whereas my function in 165 µs, so 7 times faster.

For yet biger number of rows, the advantage of my code should be
yet more visible.

## Edit following the comment as of 2020-09-07

Explanation of how *np.newaxis* works:

1. `dd` (in *fn* function) contains `array([ 0,  5, 10,  1, 20])` - the
   first column of *data*, but here it is a *1-D* array.
2. `dd[np.newaxis, :]` is a *2-D* array, containing just the same
   numbers, in a single **row**: `array([[ 0,  5, 10,  1, 20]])`.
3. `dd[:, np.newaxis]` is also a *2-D* array, but this time the
   same numbers are the content of a single **column**:

   ```
   array([[ 0],
          [ 5],
          [10],
          [ 1],
          [20]])
   ```
4. Now run `np.less(dd[np.newaxis, :], dd[:, np.newaxis]).astype(int)`
   (to facilitate the assessment of what has been computed, I added
   conversion to *int*):

   ```
   array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
   ```

   The above result is a *2-D* array, the result of comparison
   (*left_argument < right_argument*) where:

   - row number is the number of element from "row argument",
   - column number is the number of element "column argument".

   So the whole array is the result of "each to each" comparison.

   Example: The first element in row (*0*) is not less than any
   element of the column, so the first row of the result contains
   all zeroes.
5. And the last step is *sum(axis=1)*, i.e. compute sum of the above
   array along each row.

This way the final result is: `array([0, 2, 3, 1, 4])` and it will be
the first column of the whole result of *fn* function.

If you still need more explanation, search the Web for *np.newaxis*.
Even on SO you can find many explanations on this matter.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for taking the time to answer. arr is a 2D array. I have fixed the sample code to reflect that. Given the array above, the solution should be   [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]. Because in column 0, no element is less than 0, 2 elements are less than 5, 3 elements are less than 10 .... The problem is not finding a solution. I need to how to vectorize it and get rid of the for loop.

Comment: I totally replaced my initial answer with a new one, since the "old" anwer did not reflect what is actually to do in your corrected post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, we need more people like you on stack overflow. Can you please explain this line for me: (res = np.less(dd[np.newaxis, :], dd[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)).  I understand np.less, but I dont understand what is happening with the newaxis and sum